# Ubuntu server 12.04 auto installation freezes at kickseeding running if ks.cfg has post scripts

Tags: ubuntu-server, kickstart

I'm trying to make a custom Ubuntu Server iso file. Kickstart file (ks.cfg) runs smooth when there is no %post in the file and Ubuntu installs correctly with ks configuration.

Installation finishes installing base, apt, grub and It echos: Kickseed Running... and it freezes @ 0%

Installation goes well if I only add apt-get update (or something like mkdir) in %post section, but apt-get upgrade, apt-get install apache2 doesn't work

I have created dozen iso images and installed them in Virtual Box.I have been googling for 3 days and checked out ubuntu forums but haven't figured out the issue. I appreciate your help.

This is how I made the iso image. My ks.file and txt.cfg files located in isolinux directory:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/work
mount -o loop ubuntu-12.04-amd64.iso original-iso/
rsync -a original-iso/ custom-iso/
cp ks.cfg custom-iso/isolinux/
cp txt.cfg custom-iso/isolinux/
chmod -R 777 custom-iso/
#Creating Iso image
mkisofs -D -r -V “$IMAGE_NAME” -cache-inodes -J -l -b 
isolinux/isolinux.bin
-c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4
-boot-info-table
-o ~/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-custom-amd64.iso custom-iso/
```

## ks.cfg

```
#Generated by Kickstart Configurator
#platform=AMD64 or Intel EM64T

#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone America/Los_Angeles
#Root password
rootpw --iscrypted somethingsomething
#Initial user
user ubuntu --fullname "ubuntu" --iscrypted --password somethingsomething.
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
#Disk partitioning information
part /boot --size   128  --fstype=ext3 --asprimary
part /     --size   512  --fstype=ext3 --asprimary 
part swap  --size   512  
part /tmp  --size   512  --fstype=ext3
part /var  --size   512  --fstype=ext3
part /usr  --size  4096  --fstype=ext3
part /home --size  2048  --fstype=ext3
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
#Network information
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled --http --ftp --ssh 
#X Window System configuration information
xconfig --depth=32 --resolution=1024x768 --defaultdesktop=GNOME

%post
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install apache2
mkdir /home/user
```

## txt.cfg

```
default autoinstall
label autoinstall
  menu label ^Install Custom Ubuntu Server
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed 
initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet 
ks=cdrom:/isolinux/ks.cfg --

label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 
initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --

label cloud
  menu label ^Multiple server install with MAAS
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append   modules=maas-enlist-udeb vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --

label check
  menu label ^Check disc for defects
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append   MENU=/bin/cdrom-checker-menu vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --

label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus

label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY This. It should work

```
%post --interpreter=/bin/bash
#!/bin/bash 
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: Without any explanation on what is going on, I wouldn't dare try it... what is supposed to happen? What if some step fails? Why the bold, big face, etc?